# jQuery change typewriter plugin direction

Tags: jquery

i found simple plugin for news ticker, my language direction is `RTL`.unfortunately i cant change direction from `LTR` to `RTL` for this function,

i can try to change that on css but thats doesnot work correctly

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/stevenchu/ezEtK/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align:right` to the `.ticker-active` class:

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/ezEtK/232/

It's not *true* RTL since the cursor doesn't move, but a 5 second fix versus a 30 minute refactor of the plugin always gets my vote.

Comment: thanks, but for cursor move i choose this function from right to left

Comment: Have fun refactoring then. It should all be straightforward.